# How to get some data in real time from a website using python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to fetch som data from website

https://web.sensibull.com/optionchain?expiry=2020-03-26&tradingsymbol=NIFTY

[image: The ATMIV data as in the picture]
I am using beautifulsoup library to fetch this data, and have tried the following code:

```
import requests

import urllib.request

import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://web.sensibull.com/optionchain?expiry=2020-03-26&tradingsymbol=NIFTY'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

b = soup.find("div", {"class": "style__AtmIVWrapper-idZNMX kUMMRI"})

print(b)
```

But it shows "None" as the output.

Although there is only one class of this name in the full HTML code, but I also tried this:

```
for b in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'style__AtmIVWrapper-idZNMX kUMMRI'}):

    print(b.get_text())

    print(len(b))
```

But it doesn't work.

Also tried soup.find("div")
But it does not shows the required div tag in the output, maybe due to nested divs present.

Unable to fetch this data and proceed with my work. Please help.

Comment: what is the exact data you are trying to fetch?

Comment: ATM IV and NIFTY FUT data. Can be seen just in front as you open the website.

Comment: the page loads via JS you need to use selenium or similar browser tools for scraping the data. As a confirmation you can check the page source as to what is being returned from the HTML. Let me know for any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for code. This might help:-

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time
webpage = 'https://web.sensibull.com/optionchain?expiry=2020-03-26&tradingsymbol=NIFTY'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='Your/path/to/chromedriver.exe') 
driver.get(webpage)
time.sleep(10)
nifty_fut = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/button/span[1]/div[1]')
print(nifty_fut.text)
atm_iv = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')
print(atm_iv.text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I downloaded the crome webdriver from this link :

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/

Comment: extract and place it in a directory and provide the path of exe to executable_path

Comment: I downloaded the linux 64bit (I am using ubuntu 18.04 in 64 bit machine) crome webdriver from this link :

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/

After this, the extracted file is in my downloads.

I gave the path "/home/chatta/Downloads" in the above code given by you.

After running it still shows the output as 
"Loading"
"Loading"

This is the same output that came after using soup.find_all("div") and get_text():

for a in soup.find_all("div"):
    print(a.get_text())

Comment: The website takes time in opening. Just guessing if the driver might be fetching the data but as the website takes time in loading, it shows "Loading" as the output.

Could this be right?

Can we give some time.sleep() after reaching the website, and fetch the data after the website fully loads?

Comment: well, that is strange behavior. I don't know what is causing the problem. You can try to put a time.sleep(10) and check but I cannot reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a syntax problem try with `soup.find_all("div", class_="style__AtmIVWrapper-idZNMX kUMMRI")` or just `soup.find("div", class_="style__AtmIVWrapper-idZNMX kUMMRI")`

If interested in webscraping and bs4 take a look at the documentation https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find

Comment: b = soup.find("div", class_="style__AtmIVWrapper-idZNMX kUMMRI")

print(b)


This also gives the same output - "None"